# Transact SQL Procedure or Function that exists within scope of the program

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reusability

I would like to re-use code without creating a new item underneath the Programmability node in SQL Server Management Studio.

Essentially, I need to split up a field with semi-colon delimited pain scale scores and average them. So if I have a field that looks like `'6;10;7;8;9'`. I need to split out that field into the 5 individual scores and average them.

To do that, I first need to get the position of each semi-colon.

```
Delimiter1 = CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 'Worst Pain', 
    '10'), 'No Pain', 0))
Delimiter2 = CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 'Worst Pain', 
    '10'), 'No Pain', 0), CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 
    'Worst Pain', '10'), 'No Pain', 0)) + 1)
```

So instead of

```
Delimiter2 = CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 'Worst Pain', 
   '10'), 'No Pain', 0), CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 
   'Worst Pain', '10'), 'No Pain', 0)) + 1)
```

I could use

```
Delimiter2 = CHARINDEX ( ';' ,  replace(  replace(ifm.MEAS_VALUE, 'Worst Pain', 
    '10'), 'No Pain', 0), Delimiter1 + 1)
```

A function or procedure would be ideal since I could set variables for the semi-colon positions of the field in each record, divide them up into values and average.

The only thing is, I don't want a procedure or function that persists after the code is finished executing. Is there an example of someone re-using code in some modular way within the scope of the code, without leaving behind a brand new procedure or function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try making Delimiter1 a CTE (Common Table Expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary stored procedure.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

CREATE PROC #temporaryStoredProcedure
AS
BEGIN

     Do Work Here

END
GO

DROP PROC #temporaryStoredProcedure
GO
```

Of course, you wouldn't gain the benefit of cached execution plans, but it would make sure you didn't leave anything behind in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering about reusable code but providing an alternative to your code instead.

```sql
declare @S varchar(20) = '6;10;7;8;9'

select cast(replace(@S, ';', '<X/>') as xml).value('avg(text())', 'decimal(10, 2)')
```

Result:

```
8.00
```

Replace all `;` with the empty tag `<X/>`, cast to XML and extract the average value from the text values in the XML that looks like this.

```xml
6<X />10<X />7<X />8<X />9
```